# GetMenuItemInfo returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, menu

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I call this code, which is a part of a larger function that alphabetically sorts menu items (that is why I'm collecting their info to do the "swap" if needed):

```
int j = 0;

TCHAR buff_j[1024];

MENUITEMINFO mii_j = {0};
buff_j[0] = 0;
mii_j.cbSize = sizeof(mii_j);
mii_j.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM_CHECKMARKS | MIIM_DATA | MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_ID |
    MIIM_STATE | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_TYPE;
mii_j.dwTypeData = buff_j;
mii_j.cch = SIZEOF(buff_j);

if(!::GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, j, TRUE, &mii_j))
{
    //Error
    int error = ::GetLastError();   //ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
}
```

Why am I getting `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error?

Comment: According to the docs, "`MIIM_TYPE` is replaced by `MIIM_BITMAP`, `MIIM_FTYPE`, and `MIIM_STRING`". Since you're setting those three flags separately I suspect also setting `MIIM_TYPE` may be incorrect.

Comment: @JesseGood: You don't need to set those members when calling `GetMenuItemInfo`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Oh, I see. Yeah, if I remove `MIIM_TYPE` it seems to work. Thanks.